# jpa preserve order in database after update

Tags: database, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, sql-update

I use jpa 2 with hibernate 4 to persist/update objects to the database. To view these objects a web page with jsf 2 is used, which all works great.

I'm having the following problem: when i update any of the objects, the database (postgres) will put the updated object on the last row in the database. I'm wondering why this is happening? Can't the database (or is it jpa or hibernate?) just update the row and leave it where it is? The id is of course never changed.

```
INSERT INTO sector (id, code) VALUES(1, 'PRIVAAT');
INSERT INTO sector (id, code) VALUES(2, 'PUBLIEK');

Select * from sector;
```

returns in every program for querying databases:

1 privaat

2 publiek

now i update the first row:

```
update sector set code = 'privaat' where id = 1;
```

now it returns in every program:

2 publiek

1 privaat

This is also the case when using our application, which in turn uses Postgres as DB.

However, in our regression tests, which uses in memory DB HSQLDB, it returns always:

1 privaat

2 publiek

The regression tests is clearly what we expect from databases and didn't had this behavior before with other databases.

The problem is that in the web we want to preserve the order so that users don't have to search into the data: it is always a fixed position. Specially when working with a lot of referenced data for the user it is very annoying. The tests confirm this, but the application (which uses a different DB) works differently.

The only solution we have now is to put everywhere order by clauses on the id, but we would like to have a clean way of preserving the order. Using everywhere order by has also a small performance hit...

So my question is, is this due to how specific databases work (vendor-dependent)? Or is this due to JPA mapping queries in a different way depending on the dialect? If this is the second case, is there a property which can preserve the order in JPA (or maybe hibernate)?

Comment: define "last row". It updates the DB row with an UPDATE statement. YOUR QUERY is what pulls data back and that query could use an ORDER BY clause as you have said, so use the ORDER BY if you need some ordering. That's how you are supposed to guarantee ordering

Comment: i will explain with an example. i insert two rows with row 1 id=1 and row 2 id =2. when i do select all it ALWAYS returns (in any program i use) the two rows with id=1 the first row and id=2 the second row. i update a column of the row with id=1 through JPA. Now when i do select all it ALWAYS returns two rows with id=2 the first row and id=1 the second row... mystery :)

Comment: no i mean if i do a query after an update the order changes. only and only after an update the order changes.

Comment: You have provided no "example" query. Kindly update your question with real code and real query, otherwise nobody will have a clue what you are doing. And no, don't add code in the comments.

Comment: the user flussence in this post says it is due to how postgres works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369362/postgresql-changing-returned-rows-order. It is the first time we use postgres for a project and are not familiar with how it stores data in the database. However, our regression tests use in-memory HSQL DB. Which does preserve the order no mather what update you do on the tables. So our tests succeed but our application fails. Since we use JPA as u ORM framework I wanted to know if possibly JPA is the culprit as it uses specific dialects to map queries...

Comment: ok will add some queries

Comment: Rows in a relational database have no order. The ***only*** (really: the ***only***) way to get a reliable order is to use `ORDER BY` in the query. There is ***no*** alternative. Any "order" you see when not using `order by` is pure **coincidence** and can ***not*** be relied upon. You can even see a different order of results if nothing changes in the database. Plus this is again a very good example why using a different DBMS for testing than on production is a bad idea.

Comment: It is a bad idea to use different databases for testing and production. But team wanted in memory, so no much choice left for me :( i don't agree however with the statement that for all databases rows have no order. I think for certain databases rows have no order, like postgres. because if i do a test on a table with 1 million records and updates regularly, i always get the same order for HSQLDB and Oracle. I don't see coincidence there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no order there. You're just getting the semi-random order that rows happen to be read from the heap in.

Use `ORDER BY` if you want an ordering.

Some database implementations have a natural ordering because of how the data is structured (say, as a b-tree table). PostgreSQL uses a heap, so there is no order unless you ask for one.

Comment: After lookup found that Oracle and HSQLDB uses b-tree and postgres not :( will have to use orderby everywhere then... tnx

Comment: @FabiYo: Postgres uses b-tree for the indexes as well - just like Oracle and HSQLDB. And Oracle won't return the rows in any specific order either.

Comment: It depends mainly on whether the table its self is stored as a b-tree or a heap. "Clustered indexes", "index-organized tables", etc tend to have a natural ordering. Heaps do not, even if there are indexes present.